# Frenet-Serret Formulas for Arc Length and Regular Parametrization

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, frenet-frame

Frenet-Serret formulas for arc length parametrization are in matrix form where $\mathbf{ \widetilde T}(s)$, $\mathbf{ \widetilde N}(s)$, $\mathbf{ \widetilde B}(s)$ are unit tangent, normal, binormal vectors of a curve $\widetilde \alpha(s)$ of arc length parametrization as follows

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{ \widetilde T}'(s) \\ \mathbf{ \widetilde N}'(s) \\ \mathbf{ \widetilde B}'(s)
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \widetilde \kappa(s) & 0 \\ -\widetilde \kappa(s) & 0 & \widetilde \tau(s) \\ 0 & -\widetilde \tau(s) & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{ \widetilde T}(s) \\ \mathbf{ \widetilde N}(s) \\ \mathbf{ \widetilde B}(s)
\end{bmatrix}$$

In O'neill book of "*Elementary Diffetential Geometry*" on page 67, Frenet-Serret formulas for regular parametrization are defined for $\alpha(t)$ arbitrary curve as such

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{ \widetilde T}'(t) \\ \mathbf{ \widetilde N}'(t) \\ \mathbf{ \widetilde B}'(t)
\end{bmatrix}
=
\lVert \alpha(t)' \rVert
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \kappa(t) & 0 \\ -\kappa(t) & 0 & \tau(t) \\ 0 & -\tau(t) & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{ \widetilde T}(t) \\ \mathbf{ \widetilde N}(t) \\ \mathbf{ \widetilde B}(t)
\end{bmatrix}$$

In the same book under the title of "*Arbitrary-Speed Curves*" on page 66 it gives an explanation for the reason of why $t$ (arbitrary) and $s$ (arc length) parametrizations differ by speed factor $\lVert \alpha(t)' \rVert$.

By using composite function property on the same page [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qMZP.png), we can write,

$$\alpha(t)= \widetilde \alpha(s(t)) \tag{1}$$

**Question:** How can we derive Frenet-Serret formulas for arbitrary parametrization from the arc length parametrization through equation $(1)$?

Comment: It's just a simple application of the chain rule. See, for example, pp. 12-14 of my [differential geometry text](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf).

Comment: So curvature with respect to arbitrary parametrization k(t) is equal to another function generated by composite function rule when s(t)=s is plugged into curvature of arc length k(s) to make k(s(t)) and also N(t) likewise is the same as N(s(t)). However, isn't that abuse of notation? Because saying f(g(x)) = f(x) is not correct to denote as far as I know how composite functions work, but writing f(g(x)) = h(x) because plugging one function into another generates some other function. By that logic how can we write k(t) for k(s)? I hope all make sense.

Comment: Since the curve is given as a function of $t$, all the Frenet frame, curvature, and torsion, will be functions of $t$. To calculate this function of $t$, you can think of introducing the arclength reparametrization $\beta(s) = \alpha(t(s))$, where $t(s)$ is the inverse function of the arclength $s=s(t)$.

Comment: If we go from the relation $\alpha(t) =\widetilde \alpha(s(t))$ where $s(t)=s$ and take derivative of it with respect to $t$, we get:
$$\frac{d\alpha}{dt}  =\frac{d\widetilde \alpha}{ds} \frac{ds}{dt}$$
Using $\lVert \frac{d\alpha}{dt} \rVert =\frac{ds}{dt}$ in the relation above and manipulating terms, we get:
$$T(t) =\frac{\frac{d\alpha}{dt}}{\lVert \frac{d\alpha}{dt} \rVert}  =\frac{d\widetilde \alpha}{ds} =\widetilde T(s)$$
In light of these my point is if we can derive such a relation for others too, for instance, $\kappa(t) =\widetilde \kappa(s)$, $\tau(t) =\widetilde \tau(s)$, etc.

Comment: Well, yes, that's the point, except now *you* are being sloppy with notation. You need to write $\kappa(t) = \tilde\kappa(s(t))$, etc.  See the top of p. 13 of my text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serret-Frenet for Non-unit "speed" space curves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1308428/serret-frenet-for-non-unit-speed-space-curves)

Comment: I would say "almost" yes since I was rather looking for an explicit way to show the relation between arc-length and non-arc-length parametrizations of $\mathbf{T}$, $\mathbf{N}$, $\mathbf{B}$ as I showed above in my comment. I just did not get, for instance, why $\kappa(t) =\widetilde \kappa(s)$.